# Dereferencing function pointers in C to access CODE memory

Tags: c, memory, function-pointers, memcpy, bus-error

We are dealing with C here. I'm just had this idea, wondering if it is possible to access the point in memory where a function is stored, say `foo` and copying the contents of the function to another point in memory. Specifically, I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(){
    printf("Hello World");
}

int main(){

    void (*bar)(void) = malloc(sizeof foo);
    memcpy(&bar, &foo, sizeof foo);


    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

But running it gives a bus error: `Bus error: 10`. I'm trying to copy over the contents of function `foo` into a space of memory `bar` and then executing the newly created function `bar`.

This is for no other reason than to see if such a thing is possible, to reveal the intricacies of the C language. I'm not thinking about what practical uses this has.

**I'm looking for guidance getting this to work, or otherwise to be told, with a reason, why this won't work**

*EDIT* Looking at some of the answers and learning about *read*, *write*, and *executable* memory, it just dawned upon me that it would be possible to create functions on the fly in C by writing to executable memory.

Comment: I did not understand the very first statement in main.....

Comment: Have you checked that e.g. `sizeof *foo` seems even remotely valid?

Comment: @iharob Stop right here. You are not going to destroy OP's curiosity. Practical applications are unimportant for being curious about something.

Comment: @iharob Why is this a waste of time? I'm trying to reveal the intricacies of the C language.

Comment: It is not a feature of the C language, but of the CPU/OS architecture. There were so-called "self-modifying" programs in the days of DOS, which didn't have much memory protection stuff. Today it is much less likely to find an architecture allowing this.

Comment: " I'm trying to reveal the intricacies of the C language" All you reveal is undefined behaviour. Converting a function pointer to an object pointer is UB.

Comment: Are you sure `sizeof foo` isn't just going to return the size of the pointer (i.e. 4 or 8)?

Comment: Didn't realize this is UB behavior.

Comment: @Olaf False. Converting a function pointer to an object pointer is *implementation defined* and the special case of converting a function pointer to `void*` is perfectly well-defined.

Comment: @FUZxxl mentioned that problem in his answer. Is there a way to get the size of the function and not just the size of the pointer to it?

Comment: I don't think C has (or even theoretically can have) a facility to do that.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Please point me at the corresponding section in the standard.

Comment: @Olaf Please tell me where it says that it's undefined behaviour. Additionally, notice that the POSIX API (specifically, `dladdr`), requires such casts to work. It's unlikely that the C committee intended to make such a basic function undefined behaviour.

Comment: @FUZxxl: One property of "undefined behaviour" is that if it is not defined by the standard, it cannot be found in the standard. However, I found something myself. It is a [common extension](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5) (see J.5.7 for function pointer casts), which makes a program non-compliant. So, according to the standard, it **is** UB. No wonder, because on true harvard architectures code-pointers reside in a completely different space than data-pointers and there is possible no direct data-access to code-space.

Comment: Apart from the whole UB thing, `memcpy(&bar, &foo` is copying foo to the pointer bar, not to the memory block pointed to by bar.

Comment: @theideasmith Kind of a cop out answer, but you might find something fitting what you need more by looking at JIT solutions out there unless this is more of a purely academic thing. There you can generate code on the fly, capture the compiled result to a function pointer and execute the resulting machine code through the function pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With standard C, what you try to do is *implementation defined behaviour* and won't work portably. On a given platform, you might be able to make this work.

The memory `malloc` gives you is typically not executable. Jumping there causes a bus error (`SIGBUS`). Assuming you are on a POSIX-like system, either allocate the memory for the function with `mmap` and flags that cause the memory region to be executable or use `mprotect` to mark the region as executable.

You also need to be more careful with the amount of memory you provide, you cannot simply take the size of a function and expect that to be the length of the function, `sizeof` is not designed to provide this kind of functionality. You need to find out the function length using some other approach.

Comment: How do I determine the size of the function then?

Comment: @theideasmith That's not possible with standard C and I honestly don't know how you would do that. After compilation, you can use `nm -S` to find the size of functions. For a start, you could try to hard-code the function size.

Comment: Converting a function pointer to an object pointer (which includes `void *`) is not implementation defined, but undefined behaviour. In C, a function is not an object.

Comment: @Olaf: This is actually one of those holes in the spec -- it is never explicitly specified whether a function is an object or value or not.

Comment: @Olaf It is not said if functions are situated in data storage. On von Neumann systems, they are.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Please read the second half of the sentence: "..., the contents of which can represent values". This has nothing to do with CPU spaces. (but the seperation is required to **allow** support such in an implementation). Note that with memory protection units, you can implement much the same, just at a finer grain than with the fixed harvard approach. This is also the reason `sizeof(function)` yields the size of the pointer, not that of the function - a function is no object.

Comment: @Olaf “can” is not “must.” It is allowed that an object represents values but not required. For example, a trap representation doesn't represent a value either.  `sizeof` on a function yields the size of a function pointer because it's defined this way, not because functions cannot be objects.

Comment: @FUZxxl: To cut this nonsense discussion down: Please ask a new question if you still insist of a function being an object in C.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Just found in the standard: ["... If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, ...](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4). Why the differentiation if a function was an object? Such statements can be found all over the standard. E.g. in the paragraph right before (last sentence).

Comment: @Olaf the standard similarly distinguishes the different basic integer types, even though they might refer to the same underlying type.

Answer (score 6):

On modern desktops, the virtual memory manager is going to get in your way. Memory regions have three types of access: *read*, *write*, and *execute*. On systems where code segments have only *execute* permission, the `memcpy` will fail with a bus error. In the more typical case, where only code segments have the *execute* permission, you can copy the function, but not run, because the memory region that contains `bar` will not have *execute* permission.

Also, determining the size of the function is problematic. Consider the following program

```
void foo( int *x )
{
    printf( "x:(%zu %zu) ", sizeof x, sizeof *x );
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 0;
    foo( &x );
    printf( "foo:(%zu %zu)\n", sizeof foo, sizeof *foo );
}
```

On my system, the output is `x:(8 4) foo:(1 1)` indicating that taking the `sizeof` a function pointer, or the function itself, is not a supported operation.

Comment: Can I somehow give it *execute* permission?

Comment: @theideasmith FUZxxl has answered that part of the question. Interacting with the virtual memory manager is not standardized.